# How to setup an alternative algorithm to ADR?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino

I've setup a simple LoRaWAN network with a Seeeduino node and an RHF2S001 gateway module using a Raspberry pi 3. I'm working on a project where I need to setup an alternative algorithm to ADR (Adaptative data rate) using machine learning. How could I setup the network to send automatic downlinks to the node in place to inform it to change its spreading factor according to my algorithm output. I'm using loriot server to host the network.